# Python SQLite3 Programming Error about Bindings

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to create a database of video data and am having issues with the following code. The array data holds every tuple on the imported file in a list, however I cannot figure out how to get rid of the error and import the rows of data in the file into the database

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE videodata(Video_Id TEXT, Uploader TEXT, Age INT, Category TEXT, Length INT, 
Views INT, Rate INT, Ratings INT, Comments INT, Related_IDs TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(Video_ID))''')

with open('youtubedatafinal.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
  data.append(row)

c.executemany("""INSERT INTO 'videodata'('Video_Id', 'Uploader', 'Age', 'Category', 'Length', 'Views', 'Rate', 'Ratings', 'Comments', Related_IDs) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,?);""",(data,))
```

It is giving me the error

sqlite3.ProgrammingError incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 10 and there are 3169 supplied

Comment: An interesting observation. If I change the code to this                                            '''with open('youtubedatafinal.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
      data = []
      data.append(row)''' It says 1 instead of 3169

Comment: Are you sure that data has múltiple rows and has the same number columns?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the construction of your `data` list (I assume it's a list, the definition is not shown).  You presumably have 3169 rows in your csv input and it's trying to apply them as the parameters for the first execution of the sql statement.  If you print `data` you should get a hint at the structure, and how it's wrong.

Comment: Yes I believe that is the problem but I have no idea how to fix it. I want each value in the tuples to go into the corresponding column. Is there a way to get it to read the other way?

Comment: I am brand new to sqlite

Comment: Actually, try writing `executemany(. . ., data)`, without enclosing data in the tuple constructing parentheses.  Looks like you're generating a tuple with one entry, that entry containing 3169 items.

Comment: Tried that and it seemed to help however now it is saying 11 supplied not 3169. Would this be an issue with the data file?

Comment: It's likely that you have 11 values on at least one line in the file.  If you print, or otherwise examine, the contents of `data` you should see the issue.

Comment: [[(asd,kjhh,sfd,),(asdfa,sfad,asdf,)]] Its giving the data with two closed brackets on the end! How is that even possible, and how to I get it to stop that!